# How can I open an android application using another application with intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

```
try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("com.xxx.applicationname"));
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com")));
        }
```

it always enter catch scope. I don't know where I am doing wrong

Comment: What does the exception tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setPackage("package**name");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(intent);
```

and also, you should add to this line in called application manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
...
<category android:name="android.intent.category.CATEGORY_DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void launchApp(String packageName) {
    Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

    if (mIntent != null) {
        try {
            startActivity(mIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException err) {
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Not FOund", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, it is a dummy question, but Shall I put into same folder these two project? or should I import project one from another?
because when I tried that, it opens only one project, it doesnt launch another

Comment: To be honest, I didn't get ur question! I think you need to know this:
If the app (packageName) that you want to launch exists (i.e app is installed) in your device, then it will be opened automatically with code above. You don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.xxx.app");

if (intent != null)
    startActivity(intent);
else
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "app is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```